# Android RecyclerView doesn't show items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Please, help to figure out why my implementation of `RecyclerView` doesn't show anything.

Retrieving data asynchronously and result is successfull, but don't know how to display it correctly.

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        checkAndRequestPermissions(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RssService.runRssFeed(newsList -> {
            System.out.println("SIZE ----- " + newsList.size());
            adapter.setItems(newsList);
        });

    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<NewsModel> news = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void setItems(List<NewsModel> news) {
        this.news.addAll(news);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearItems() {
        this.news.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
        holder.date.setText(news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDate());
        holder.link.setText(news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLink());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return news.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView title, date, link;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            title = view.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            date = view.findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);
            link = view.findViewById(R.id.linkTxt);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

news_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The only issue I could find was with your data binding. the outermost view of activity_main.xml should be <layout></layout>. In between this write rest of your xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It showed correctly but you can't see because your text color is white

Answer (score 1):

```
**issue in these lines** 


 holder.title.setText(news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
        holder.date.setText(news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDate());
        holder.link.setText(news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLink());
```

change these like

```
 holder.title.setText(news.get(position).getTitle());
```